# Open and close additional window (QML)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Currently I have a window openning in the following way:

```
property variant win
Button {
    id: testButton
    MouseArea {
        onClicked: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("test.qml");
            win = component.createObject(testButton);
            win.show();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is it ok to create a window like this or there is a better way to do it (from QML, not from C++)?
2. When I close this additional window (just by clicking "x" button), I want to connect it to another event (for example, changing color of the button). How to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note: The datatype `variant` is deprecated. Use `var` instead - and only if necessary. As you will stuff a `Window` in it, use `property Window win` instead. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-variant.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is usually nicer to have it more declarative. If you want your button to only open one window, the usage of a `Loader` might be right for you.
I think this is what you want, as you store it in one variable, and if you click the button multiple times, you would lose access to your instance. If you need a larger amount of `Windows` created by the same `Button`, you might use a `ListModel` and a `Instantiator` to create the instances.

With the `Loader` this might look like this:

```
Button {
    id: ldbutton
    onClicked: winld.active = true
    Rectangle {
        id: ldindic
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        width: height
        color: winld.active ? 'green' : 'red'
    }

    Loader {
        id: winld
        active: false
        sourceComponent: Window {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: 'green'
            visible: true
            onClosing: winld.active = false
        }
    }
}
```

In this code is also already the answer to your second question: The signal you are looking for is called [`closing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#closing-signal) - connect to it to do what ever is necessary.

In the case of the `Loader` it is necessary to unload the window, so it can be loaded again later, maybe. If you have the window created by a `Instantiator`, you need to remove the corresponding index from the `Instantiator`'s `ListModel`.

This might look like this:

```
Button {
    id: rpbutton
    onClicked: rpmodel.append({})
    text: 'Open Windows ' + rpmodel.count

    ListModel {
        id: rpmodel
    }

    Instantiator { // from QtQml 2.0
        model: rpmodel
        delegate: Window {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: 'blue'
            visible: true
            onClosing: rpmodel.remove(index)
        }
    }
}
```

In your code you could connect to it, either by using a `Connection`-object, that connects to your property `win`, or by changing the JS `onClicked` like so:

```
onClicked: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("test.qml");
    win = component.createObject(testButton);
    win.closing.connect(function() { console.log('do something') })
    win.show();
}
```

Comment: For some reason I have `onClosing` marked as `invalid property` (using `Qt.Quick.Window 2.2`). I have seen other people reporting same problem as well, but no solution. Do you know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a warning thrown, or is it just the QtCreator complaining? If so, that is due to a bug that seems to reappear with every new version :-) but I assume it can be safely ignored.

Comment: The window switching is not smooth. Is this QML issue or because of this implement way. Especially when the new windows is full screen.

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean by "not smooth"? What happens, and what would you like to happen?