# Spawn QtQuick UI file from a normal QML Window class

Tags: qt, qml

How does one display a QtQuick UI fileset (ui.qml and .qml) from a normal QML Window?

To display other QML windows from my parent Window class, the call is, roughly:

```
                var component = Qt.createComponent("SubWindow.qml")
                var window    = component.createObject(window)
                window.show()
```

I've tried calling both the QtQuickUISubwindow.ui.qml and QtQuickUISubwindow.qml, but neither works.

Are QtQuickUI files not meant to be sub windows?

Comment: **1.** Why do you create windows with JS, when you could do it with QML. **2.** No, QtQuickUI files can't have `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` as root element. (*Try to manually change the root element of a .ui.qml-file to `Window` and open it in the designer to see [Error M220](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html)*).

Comment: See also [**here**](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html): *"The following features are not supported: [...] Root items that are not derived from QQuickItem or Item [...]"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` and `ApplicationWindow` are not of Type `Item` (or `QQuickItem`). This however is a requirement for being placed as a root item in a `.ui.qml`-file as [stated in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html):

> The following features are not supported:
>
> - [...]
> - Root items that are not derived from QQuickItem or Item

So the answer is:

> **No, you can't use QtQuickUI files neither as windows nor as sub windows.**

---

You can however easily use them *within a sub window*

// main.qml

```
Window {
    id: root
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    Loader { // creates my sub window without JS
        id: winLoader
        active: false // Change to create the window.
        sourceComponent: Window {
            width: srcLoader.item ? srcLoader.item.width : 0
            height: srcLoader.item ? srcLoader.item.height : 0
            visible: srcLoader.item
            Loader {
                id: srcLoader
                source: "QtQuickUISubwindow.ui.qml" // Your ui.qml-file *here*
                active: true
            }
            onClosing: winLoader.active = false
        }
    }
    Button {
        text: "Show sub window!"
        onClicked: winLoader.active = true
    }
}
```

This code has not been tested by me. Maybe I'll do so later once I have access to a Qt machine. How to initialize multiple windows with a repeater and a `ListModel` you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47018205/2056452

You might pass the `source` of the `srcLoader` to the model, and read it from there if you want to open multiple different windows.

---

You can ofc modify the `QtQuickUISubwindow.qml`-file and add a `Window` or `ApplicationWindow` of the appropriate size as the root element. Then you can create everything as you used to do, using JS - and hope that the garbage collector plays nicely.

Comment: I tried your the QML code, but wasn't able to get it working, the documentation spec is really the correct answer and I appreciate you pointing it out.

Comment: I forgot to make the root window visible, and I have another name for the `ui.qml`-file. Now I also added a button, to activate the `Loader`.